# display images through javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-staticfiles

I am working on quiz project using Django where I have to show an image on 5 different questions, handled by javascript. But somehow the images are not being shown:
Here is code in js file:

```
    if(ques_no == 4 || ques_no == 8 || ques_no == 9 || ques_no == 13 || ques_no == 16)
{
  if(ques_no == 4)
  {
    document.getElementById("img").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage="url('images/soccercity.jpg')";
  }
  if(ques_no == 8)
  {
    document.getElementById("img").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage="url('images/Portugal_badge.png')";
  }
  if( ques_no == 9)
  {
    document.getElementById("img").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage="url('images/Ragnar-Klavan.jpeg')";
  }
  if(ques_no == 13)
  {
    document.getElementById("img").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage="url('images/rcd.png')";
  }
  if(ques_no == 16)
  {
    document.getElementById("img").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage="url('images/zakumi.png')";
  }
```

Here is code for css file which is working fine:

```
.background{
 background-image: url("images/football.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position: relative;
 min-height:100vh;
 }
```

Although when I display image through CSS, it works perfectly fine, but not through js file. Maybe the fault is in defining the URL but then it's working fine through CSS then why not js.

Images are stored in the images sub-directory of static directory.
.js and .css files are stored in static directory.

Comment: `Here is the image of my js file` No, don't create pictures of code, post the *actual code*

Comment: okay. Let me upload it.

Comment: Thanks. Your syntax and style assignments all look to be fine. I'd first check to see if the whole `if` block is being entered at all, and if it is, then check your network tab to see if the image is being found on the server

Comment: The problem is not in code. It is working perfectly fine if not rendered using django. The problem seems to be with static files or path name.

Comment: Yep, that's why i suggested `check your network tab to see if the image is being found on the server`

Comment: its written that image not found.   Not Found: /quiz/images/soccercity.jpg

Answer (score 0):

it works fine for me, here is my `HTML` code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>
<div id="img" class="background">

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" class="background"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The display block is very redundant and unnecessary in your code, but it's not causing the issue.

```
document.getElementById("img").style.display="block";
```

My `JavaScript`

```
if(ques_no == 4 || ques_no == 8 || ques_no == 9 || ques_no == 13 || ques_no == 16)
{
  if(ques_no == 4)
  {
    document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage="url('images/soccercity.jpg')";
  }
  else if(ques_no == 8)
  {
    document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage="url('images/Portugal_badge.png')";
  }
  else if( ques_no == 9)
  {
    document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage="url('images/Ragnar-Klavan.jpeg')";
  }
  else if(ques_no == 13)
  {
    document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage="url('img.jpg')";
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage="url('images/zakumi.png')";
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: If rendered using django, its not working. Otherwise it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: Please share how are you rendering in Django.